# CSS3 percentage value not taking using resized viewport, using old viewport size instead

Tags: javascript, css, viewport

I have a element that has this animation that pops up from the bottom of the edge of the screen and pops down(not totally down though) in a loop. The code below works great for this. However, there is a issue. When the browser goes full screen the percentages account for the old viewport size rather than the new viewport size...making the percentages off. What can I do about this? I write raw javascript if there is a way with this also.

```
#chronoPopUp {
    font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: white;
    display: block;
    width: 1300px;
    height: 37%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    margin-top: 661px;
    margin-left: 60px;
    -webkit-animation: slideUp 1s linear;
    border-top-right-radius: 25px;
    border-top-left-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom: none;
}

#chronoPopDown {
    -webkit-animation: slideDown 1s linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideDown {
        0% { -webkit-transform: translateY(0%); }
        100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(75%); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideDownAllTheWay {
        0% { -webkit-transform: translateY(0); }
        100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(100%); }
}


@-webkit-keyframes slideUp {
        0% { -webkit-transform: translateY(75%); }
        100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(0%); }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="chronoPopUp" class="clickChronop">
    <div id="chronoCircle" class="clickChrono">
        <div id="circleLine1" class="clickChrono"></div>
        <div id="circleLine2" class="clickChrono"></div>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
var chronoListViewDisplay = function() {
    var displayActive = true;
    var toggleStatus = true;
    var rotationAutomationSteps = [];
    var automatedRotationTimer;

    function toggleChronoListView(slideDown) {
        var element = document.getElementById("chronoPopUp");
        slideDown = typeof slideDown !== "undefined" ? slideDown : "slideDown";
        console.log(slideDown);
        if (toggleStatus) {
            element.style.webkitAnimation = slideDown + " 1s linear forwards";
            toggleStatus = false;
        } else {
            element.style.webkitAnimation = "slideUp" + " 1s linear forwards";
            toggleStatus = true;
        }
    }

    function rotationEngine() {
        console.log("hi");
        //always start with a slide up
        rotationAutomationSteps[0] = setTimeout(toggleChronoListView, 2000);
        toggleStatus = false;
        rotationAutomationSteps[1] = setTimeout(toggleChronoListView, 4000);
    }


    function runAutomatedRotation() {
        rotationEngine();
        automatedRotationTimer = setInterval(rotationEngine, 4000);
    }

    return {
        toggleChronoListView : toggleChronoListView,
                             toggleStatus: toggleStatus,
                             runAutomatedRotation: runAutomatedRotation,
    }

}();
```

UPDATED: Please see http://jsfiddle.net/3vecy/ for example. Hitting F11 full screen mode will show it not sliding down to the same level as if it out of full screen mode.

Comment: Make sure your element's container is resizing with the window, remember percentages are relative to the container.

Comment: When hitting the F11 key to make the browser go to full screen mode,is this actually considered a resize to the viewport?

Comment: I tried height: 37% isntead of px for the element but still did not dynamically resize.

Comment: Could you show your css and html?

Answer (score 2):

What browser are you texting in? If it is a problem with IE, and you are using an external stylesheet, try adding this to your `<link rel='stylesheet'>` in your `<head>`.
This may work on other browsers.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/nameofstylesheet.css?v=2'>
```

See, just add a version query to the `href` of your `<link>`.

Comment: This is in a recent version of Chromium. Still no success.

Comment: I am using chrome as my browser. Can I possibly see a fiddle and test it in Chrome 32?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3vecy/  If you hit F11 for fullscreen after watching it, you will see that it will not slide down to the same level as if it was in full screen.

Comment: It works perfectly on JSFiddle on chrome 32. You just have to scroll down a little. Well, that's not what you want, though. You want it to go to 75% of the top of the page. Also, hitting F11 in a fiddle will only fullscreen the whole fiddle window, not the result/output. I will try to run your code in a local HTML file. _edit_ I found a way to run it fullscreen. It animates but does not go to 75% of the top.

Comment: "It animates but does not go to 75% of the top"...yep that is the issue

Comment: I could but then out of fullscreen mode it would be off

Comment: I know the problem. Percentages always apply to the size of the browser window/viewport, not the height of the `<body>`. So if the page's height is `200%`, then you should set the `translateY()` to `150%`. Check my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wEUL4/1/).

Comment: Unfortunately, I found the issue with a javascript eventlistener for screen resize. If the browser is set to full screen, the viewport doesn't change...even though it really does.

Comment: This is probably too late to help you, but try using the new CSS3 responsive `vw` (viewport-width) and `vh` (viewport-height) units. for Example, like this. so instead of 75%, try `75vh`